# Multiple split buttons on jQuery Mobile list

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have multiple split buttons in a jQuery mobile list?

I've tried doing this:

```
<ul data-role='listview'>
    <li>
        <a href='#' id='1'>1</a>
        <a href='#' id='btn1'></a>
        <a href='#' id='btn2'></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work. Neither does wrapping the links in a `<div data-role='controlgroup>`. Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible without a hack?

**UPDATE**: The list is dynamically generated by doing `$("#listid).append("<li>...</li>")`. http://jsfiddle.net/nrpMN/3/ . As pointed out by mdmullinax below, the following does work:

```
<ul data-role='listview'>
    <li>
       <a href='#' id='1'>1</a>
        <div data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal'>
            <a href='#' id='btn1'></a>
            <a href='#' id='btn2'></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a horizontal `controlgroup` nested in a `listview`.

http://jsfiddle.net/nrpMN/

```
<ul data-role='listview'>
    <li>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, but if you're generating the list dynamically, it doesn't. I know I didn't specify dynamic generation of the list in my question, but I assumed that it wouldn't make a difference. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrpMN/3/

Comment: according to this [JQM FAQ](http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html) there's a new `.trigger('create')` method (as of beta2) for this very thing. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/nrpMN/4/).  There was also a missing attribute on the buttons: `data-role="button"`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I think I had an older beta 2 (although it was still beta 2). :)

Comment: @Jayraj, this doesn't seem to work properly. For me the buttons appear below the first anchor (a tag) rather than to the right. Also, an arrow icon appears.

Comment: @Tom A JSFiddle would be useful, in order to see what's going on. Also, the last fiddle that mdmullinax posted in the comments (http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/nrpMN/4/) works. Maybe the new JQM release broke/changed something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is extension to the solution. Problem with above solution is that you cannot control the placement of buttons on the right side of the list item. One way to do it is add class='ui-li-aside' to the  control. That will make the buttons come on right, but you will have to adjust the area which aside covers, by default it is 50%. You can modify it to reduce it so that it does not cover your list content on left

```
.ui-li-aside { float: right; width: 10%; text-align: right; margin: .3em 0; }
```

Or you can add another class

```
.ui-li-asideNew { float: right; width: 10%; text-align: right; margin: .3em 0; }
```

And change the div to adjust the

```
<ul data-role='listview'>
    <li>
        <div class='ui-li-aside' data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Controlgroup not rendered well in dynamic listview. You should make complete html code for controlgroup in dynamic listview.

```
<li>
  <a href='#popupItem' data-rel='popup'>List Text</a>
  <div class='ui-controlgroup-controls' style='width: 110px;float: right;position: absolute;right: 0em;top: 0.5em;'><a href='#' id='tolistminus' data-role='button' data-icon='minus' data-iconpos='notext' style='width: 1.0em;float: left;' data-theme='b' class='ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-first-child' role='button'>-1</a><a href='#' id='tolistplus' data-role='button' data-icon='plus' data-iconpos='notext' style='width: 1.0em;float: left;' data-theme='b' class='ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-last-child' role='button'>+1</a></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some suggestions:
  1. Please format your code better; it's hard to read when everything is on one line.
  2. It's not really clear what you are saying. If you aren't able to describe your solution well in words, try saying it with code: put it on http://jsfiddle.net or similar service.
  3. Alternatively (or in addition) you could also post a screenshot to show what you mean by "Controlgroup not rendered well"