# Listview with more than one split button?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

Based on the JQuery-Mobile example of the [Split button list](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html) I am trying to generate a listview component in Android with two extra buttons to the right, one next to the other. The problem is that the code generates only one button and the second one is added as a link to the current item.

Here is my code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="b">
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('the item!');">
      <h3>The item</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('1st splitbutton!');">1st link</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('2nd splitbutton!');">2nd link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what it generates:

[image: This is what I have now]

And something like this is what I am trying to produce:

[image: This is what I want to generate]

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: here's a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059608/multiple-split-buttons-on-jquery-mobile-list)

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a duplicate. I just tested it and the answer code in that question produces a `<li>` with three buttons of the same size in it, and I want to generate a `<li>` with the main item link and two extra buttons, like in the image.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the same as the linked article is trying to, but he gave up and came up with a different solution - just thought that might help you move on

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able at last to achieve something similar:

[image: The result! :)]

In case anyone is interested, here is the final code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="b" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('the item!');">
      <h3>The item</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('1st splitbutton!');" class="split-button-custom" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">1st link</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('2nd splitbutton!');" class="split-button-custom" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext">2nd link</a>
    <a href="#" style="display: none;">Dummy</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the new defined classes:

```
.split-button-custom {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -32px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em 1em;
    border-top-right-radius: 1em 1em;   
}

.split-button-custom span.ui-btn-inner {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em 1em;
    border-top-right-radius: 1em 1em;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.split-button-custom span.ui-icon {
    margin-top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for this. I am after the same kind of effect.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by Pablo's answer

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="cover" src="images/cover.jpg"/>
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </a>
        <div class="split-custom-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" class="split-custom-button" data-icon="gear" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" class="split-custom-button" data-icon="delete" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="notext"></a>           
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

by placing the links in a wrapper div there's no need for a 'dummy' anchor (and can take more than two anchors).

css styling gives the buttons the same height as the listitem, so the accessibility is the same as the standard split button

```
.split-custom-wrapper {
    /* position wrapper on the right of the listitem */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.split-custom-button {
    position: relative;
    float: right;   /* allow multiple links stacked on the right */
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    min-width:3em;
    /* remove boxshadow and border */
    border:none;
    moz-border-radius: 0;
    webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    moz-box-shadow: none;
    webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.split-custom-button span.ui-btn-inner {
    /* position icons in center of listitem*/
    position: relative;
    margin-top:50%;
    margin-left:50%;
    /* compensation for icon dimensions */
    top:11px; 
    left:-12px;
    height:40%; /* stay within boundaries of list item */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/YneYY/

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="cover" src="images/cover.jpg"/>
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </a>
        <div class="split-custom-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" class="split-custom-button" data-icon="gear" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" class="split-custom-button" data-icon="delete" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="notext"></a>           
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="cover" src="images/cover.jpg"/>
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </a>
        <div class="split-custom-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" class="split-custom-button" data-icon="gear" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" class="split-custom-button" data-icon="delete" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="notext"></a>           
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS Fiddle clreated for Arney's example

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option to acomplish the same thing

http://jsfiddle.net/wZg75/

```
<ul data-role='listview'>
    <li >
        <a>i can run
        </a>
        <p>test</p> 
        <p>test</p> 
        <p>test</p> 
        <p>test</p> 
        <div position=relative align=right data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
<ul data-role="listview" >
                    <li>
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 60%;">
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                    <h2>Manikandan</h2>
                                    <p>Email : tomanikandan.j@gmail.com</p>
                                    <p>Store Name : Mani Store</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width: 40%; padding-top: 20px; float: right;">
                                <div style="float: right;">
                                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="edit" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">Edit</a>
                                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">Delete</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/_assets/js/index.js"></script>
<script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true">
      <li><a href="#" style="margin-right:5em">
       <img src="../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">
       <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
       <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
       <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" style="right: 2.5em;border-radius:0" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
       <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">
       <img src="../_assets/img/album-hc.jpg">
       <h2>Warning</h2>
       <p>Hot Chip</p></a>
       <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" style="right: 2.5em;border-radius:0" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
       <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">
       <img src="../_assets/img/album-p.jpg">
       <h2>Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h2>
       <p>Phoenix</p></a>
       <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" style="right: 2.5em;border-radius:0" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
       <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <div data-role="popup" id="purchase" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px; padding-bottom:2em;">
      <h3>Purchase Album?</h3>
      <p>Your download will begin immediately on your mobile device when you purchase.</p>
      <a href="index.html" data-rel="back" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Buy: $10.99</a>
      <a href="index.html" data-rel="back" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Cancel</a>
     </div>
```

### Broken Bells

Broken Bells

Purchase album
                            Purchase album

### Warning

Hot Chip

Purchase album
                            Purchase album

### Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix

Phoenix

Purchase album
                            Purchase album

```
                <div data-role="popup" id="purchase" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px; padding-bottom:2em;">
                    <h3>Purchase Album?</h3>
                    <p>Your download will begin immediately on your mobile device when you purchase.</p>
                    <a href="index.html" data-rel="back" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Buy: $10.99</a>
                    <a href="index.html" data-rel="back" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Cancel</a>
                </div>
```